# Restrict User Category Access

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, administration

I am using magento 1.7 community edition is there is any way to restrict user's
in publishing products in some specific categories.

Comment: Not with Magento as it ships out of the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Roscius said, not out of the box. However Aitoc offers an extension that does add this feature and some other nice ones, It's called [Advanced Permissions](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advanced-permissions.html).

In the screenshot below you can see it offers access restricted by store and by category. I haven't used the latest versions but older ones had pretty decent code.
[image]

Comment: good but was seeking for free alternative.

Comment: I'f afraid you'll have to build it yourself but if you do find it please share!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/catalog-permissions.html 
 
This will restrict customers of particular customer groups to see particular categories.